# htaccess redirect file request of one to another file

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need modificate file request  `http://subdomain.site.com/file.txt -> http://site.com/file-subdomain.txt`
Please help with htaccess code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(subdomain)\.(site\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^file\.txt$ http://%2/file-%1.txt [L,R=301,NC]
```

**EDIT:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(subdomain)\.(site\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^file\.txt$ /file-%1.txt [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you! but how to make the address in the browser
has not changed?

Comment: Since domains are changing therefore URL in browser will also change. Only way out is to use `mod_proxy`. Let me know if you have it enabled and then I can post an answer for that as well.

Comment: If I do not change the domain, is it possible not to change the address in the browser? http://subdomain.site.com/file.txt -> http://subdomain.site.com/file-subdomain.txt

Comment: Yes that will work without changing domain, see edited answer.